# Is the set $\overline{\langle \{ f^{*}_{1}f_2: f_1,f_2\in J\}\rangle } $ equal to $B(\ell^2)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

If $J=\left\lbrace f\in B(\ell^2): f^*(e_1)=0
\right\} $,  is the set
$\overline{\langle \{ f^{*}_{1}f_2: f_1,f_2\in J\}\rangle } $ equal to $B(\ell^2)$?

( $\ell ^2 $ is the Hilbert space $(\ell^2, \lVert.\rVert
_2)   $ and
$B(\ell^2) $ is the C$^*$-algebra of bounded operators on $\ell^2$ and $e_1=(1,0,0,0,\ldots )$ 
and the symbol $\langle .\rangle $ means the linear span of inside it )

I know  $J$ is a closed right ideal and $\langle J,J 
\rangle $ is two sided ideal; and
$ \langle J,J\rangle \supseteq J$ with the properties of approximate unit, But  $\langle J,J\rangle =?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you don't even need to take the span nor the closure. That is,
$$
J_0=\{f_1^*f_2: f_1,f_2\in J\}=B(H). 
$$
Let $S$ be the unilateral shift. Then $S^*e_1=0$, so $S\in J$. Thus $ST\in J$ for all $T\in B(H)$. And then 
$$
T=(T^*)^*S^*S=(ST^*)^*S\in J_0. 
$$